# Adding non distinct elements to a dictionary

Tags: c#

Suggestions on a good pattern to follow to add elements to a dictionary where you want to add an element if it does not exist, else do nothing

The 2 approaches I can think of are

```
if(!dict.CcontainsKey(i))
    dict.Add(i,true);
```

And

```
try
{
    dict.Add(i,true);
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
//Do Nothing
}
```

In the case where repetitions are expected to be minimal, is the 2nd method preferred?

Comment: Do you have performance issues related to those two lines? Don't sacrifice readability for performance without doing so for a very good reason.

Comment: No @JeroenVannevel, I dont have any performance issues, its a reasonably small and fast piece of code

Comment: You seem to be confusing an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) with a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern).

Comment: BTW, if you post code samples, it's better if they actually compile (no missing semicolons) and are indented properly.

Comment: @svick Sorry about that, meant to post them as pseudo code instead...

Comment: Perhaps a `HashSet<T>` is a better fit than a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use exceptions for flow control. Beside that, your first version is shorter, more understandable, more obviously correct (I don't have to check the docs that `ArgumentException` is the right exception type) and most likely more efficient.

Because of all that, the first version is a much better choice.

Comment: While I agree exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control, option 1, in multiple thread situations along with bad luck, can lead to a race condition resulting in an unhandled exception. There are scenarios where 2 is more appropriate.

Comment: @whatsisname If you have multiple threads, then neither option is safe without a lock. So no, option 2 wouldn't be more appropriate.

Comment: Agree 100% must first take care to ensure that the exception will not be thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view I would always go for the first approach: it is readable, do not contains the ugly try-catch block, and clearly contains the intent.
Are you sure it should be an exception when adding and failing? Worse, you do nothing in that case. I'm not sure that is the intent of the code.
First one also seems more the desired logic.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you want your code to react.

If you simply want do do 'nothing', I'd prefer the first way, you suggested. It's simple, and clean.

The exception could be useful, if you do not expect any duplicate elements, but there suddenly are. You can handle that exception in the catch-block, for example, tell the user, that such an element already exists, or 'rethrow' it to the caller. Going that way, you enable someone else to react, if any duplicate element is detected.

Answer (score 1):

As @svick pointed out, one should not use exceptions for flow control.

Doubtful approach #2 also introduced a potential bug into your code, or at least behavior that you haven't foreseen (these both are synonymous to me).

The thing is that trying to duplicate a key is not the only case where `Dictionary` would throw an `ArgumentException`. Another one is attempting to add `null` to the `Dictionary` (in which case an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown, to be precise - but it's a subclass of `ArgumentException`, so it will still be handled by your `catch` clause).

Dictionaries in C# don't accept nulls as keys. If `i` happens to be null, then we've got some information which can't be persisted in `dict`, and it could indicate there's something wrong elsewhere in your code. But this piece of code that you posted carelessly gobbles this important warning signal, making it more difficult to identify the root cause of the bug in future.

That's another reason for not relying on exceptions when you don't need to, especially not relying on them in the way that gets your code to ignore them...

And finally, I would suggest that you use the third approach:

```
dict[i] = true;
```

Definitely the cleanest. You would know it if you took a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Checking documentation is the best way of preventing oneself from reinventing the wheel. You don't need to come up with your own "pattern", it's already there for you.

(With this solution I assume that your code never has to set any values back to `false` - the snippets you posted don't imply it).